# Scrollable table body inside of header and footer

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollable

I'm trying to create a widget on a page that is a table with a thead, tbody and tfoot. Because I don't want the widget to become too large, if the tbody were to be longer than about 200px from having many rows, I'd like the rows inside the table to be scrollable.

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 but I would prefer a purely CSS/HTML solution if that is possible.

Does anyone have a very easy solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the overflow css declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow:auto;">
<div id="widget">

<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>more blah</td>
        <td>etc</td>
        <td>etc</td>
        <td>etc</td>
        <td>etc</td>
        <td>etc</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>   
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>


</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is I only want the content of the table (the "tbody") to scroll. The header and footer of the table ("thead" and "tfoot") should stay in place.

Comment: you could add the same declaration to anything including the tbody too :)

Comment: I tried this css:
table.scheduleWidget tbody{
 width: 250px;
 height: 30px;
 overflow: auto;
}
but curiously it doesn't do anything at all. :(

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that if I tried something like tbody{height:1000px}, it doesn't increase the height of the table. It ignores the height entirely.

Comment: could you set up a jsfiddle please so that i can have a play and see if i can help?

Comment: Sure, I really appreciate your help. Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lukewarm74/4EnuE/

Comment: Also, I found that making the tbody display:block will make it scroll, but it causes the cells inside to not take up the full width. =\